# how to get latest value and remove old value?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a sql command that will get lastest value everytime user ask question or answer question .But there is an error that when i get answer value , it get all answer & question . I want to get only the latest asnwer. Example :

```
|    postid | type    | parentid | 
|---------  |---------|-----------
| 97        |       A |         92 
| 96        |       A |         93
| 95        |       A |         93
| 94        |       Q |        NULL
| 93        |       Q |        NULL
| 92        |       Q |        NULL
| 91        |       Q |        NULL
```

I tried to use groupby(parentid) . But it don't get any question . Like this:

```
|    postid | type    | parentid | 
|---------  |---------|-----------
| 97        |       A |         92
| 96        |       A |         93
```

But I want to get : 
    the latest answer (don't get answer before of this answer + the question of this answer) 
    the question (if don't have answer , keep this question )

```
|    postid | type    | parentid | 
|---------  |---------|-----------
| 97        |       A |         92
| 96        |       A |         93
| 94        |       Q |        NULL
| 91        |       Q |        NULL
```

here is my code :

```
 SELECT `p`.* 
FROM `qa_posts` `p`
JOIN `user_member` `u` ON u.user_id = p.userid
LEFT JOIN `user_profile` `pr` ON u.user_id = pr.user_id
WHERE p.is_deleted =0
GROUP BY `p`.`parent_id`
ORDER BY `p`.`postid` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Please tidy up your question by showing us all three tables.

Comment: Add check in where clause that `p`.`parent_id` is not null

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : it just username, and userprofile .I think it not important because I just want to get value forn qa_posts

Comment: @sayani try IS NOT NULL but it still don't get question value . It just get answer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select max(postid), type, parentid
  from posts
    group by type, parentid
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/357ce/1

**edit**
Okay it seems I may have misunderstood, and that you want all unanswered questions, PLUS the latest answer for every other question, but NOT those questions that have an answer? If so, we can do this quite easily with a `UNION`, this will do it:

```
select max(postid) p, type, parentid
  from posts
    where type = 'A'
    group by parentid
union
  select p1.postid, p1.type, p1.parentid
    from posts p1
      left join posts p2
        on p1.postid = p2.parentid
      where p2.parentid is null and p1.type = 'Q'
order by p desc;
```

With an updated fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05667/17

Comment: the answer  is ok . But can I get all the question value? . Your sql just get the latest answer value .
I want to get :
the latest answer (remove answer before od this answer + the question of this answer)
the question (if don't have answer , keep this question )

Comment: Let me rephrase that to see if i have it right. You want all questions that have no answer, and the latest answer to all questions that have answers, but NO questions that do have answers?

Comment: thank you for your enthusiasm.your code work perfectly . It's help me alot :D

Comment: when I add values (98, 'A', 93) to your code . It not return postid desc , it return 97 98 94 91  . I just fixed for people who need it:
select max(postid) as postid, type, parentid from posts where type = 'A' group by parentid
union
  select p1.postid, p1.type, p1.parentid from posts p1 left join posts p2
        on p1.postid = p2.parentid
      where p2.parentid is null and p1.type = 'Q' order by postid

Comment: i added the ordering into the answer for completeness